# pandas split-apply-combine with results returned to original DataFrame

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to document a particular case of the ['split-apply-combine'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) method here.

The issue: I start with a DataFrame and I have to do some processing of the data that requires a groupby split and returns some results. Let's further assume that the processing cannot be accomplished by a simple built-in operation (there are shortcuts for that), but it is complex enough that I have to loop through the groups. Furthermore, I want the results to be put back into the original DataFrame. (Yes, I know, if the result is a *single scalar* for the whole group, I will be waisting memory. However, often I do want to have those results in the original data table rather than deal with another table).

I have found that this case is poorly documented both in the pandas documentation and here.

Let's illustrate with an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Prepare DataFrame
data = {'Group':['A']*4+['B']*4+['C']*4,'Prop1':['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','S6','S7','S8','S9','S10',
'S11','S12'],'Prop2':[2004,2004,3004,3004,4004,4004,5004,5004,6004,6004,7004,7004],
'Res1':[0,1,2,3,10,11,12,13,20,21,22,23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df
```

[image: Initial DataFrane]

Now we go ahead with the groupby operation and the calculation of the new results:

```
df['Res2'] = np.nan
df['Res3'] = np.nan
grouped = df.groupby('Group')
for (key,gr) in grouped:
    # Calculate two new results based on gr values
    res2 = gr['Res1'].mean()
    gr['Res2'] = res2
    res3 = gr['Prop2'] + gr['Res1']
    gr['Res3'] = res3
    # At this point gr has two new columns Res2 and Res3
    # Now we need to copy those changes back to the original DataFrame df
    df.update(gr)
```

The tricky part here is putting the results back into `df`. Notice that I had to first create the two new columns in `df`, otherwise that would not work. The first method is to use the `.update` command. This is easy to read. Using the `%timeit` command, I timed this at (1.85ms, 1.84ms, 1.74ms).

A second method to do the same is to note that the original index is preserved in `gr`. So we can just replace `df.update(gr)` with:

```
df.loc[gr.index,('Res2','Res3')] = gr[['Res2','Res3']]
```

After either of those cells, we get the desired result (along with the notorious `SettingWithCopy` warning):

[image: final result]

Interestingly enough, the second method is slightly faster, timing at (1.66ms,1.69ms,1.73ms).

The question I have is, is there an easier way?
And, how is this done for a DataFrame with row multi-index?

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform for Res2 and Res3 is simply the sum. No need to create two new columns

```
df['Res2'] = df.groupby('Group').Res1.transform('mean')
df['Res3'] = df['Prop2'] + df['Res1']

    Group   Prop1   Prop2   Res1    Res2    Res3
0   A   S1  2004    0   1.5     2004
1   A   S2  2004    1   1.5     2005
2   A   S3  3004    2   1.5     3006
3   A   S4  3004    3   1.5     3007
4   B   S5  4004    10  11.5    4014
5   B   S6  4004    11  11.5    4015
6   B   S7  5004    12  11.5    5016
7   B   S8  5004    13  11.5    5017
8   C   S9  6004    20  21.5    6024
9   C   S10 6004    21  21.5    6025
10  C   S11 7004    22  21.5    7026
11  C   S12 7004    23  21.5    7027
```

Comment: the particular calculations here are just examples that are meant to stand in for more complicated stuff. I now realize that I picked an unfortunate one, just the sum, which, as you note, can also be calculated directly.